# Not able to connect to mongodb cluster via lambda functions

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a mongoDB cluster running on AWS and the MONGO_URI is of the format:

`mongodb://<user>:<password>@host1.example.com:27017,host2.example.com:27017/?ssl=true&ssl_ca_certs=<path/to/ca.pem>&replicaSet=<replicaSetName>`

Since I have a dependency of `ca.pem`, I created a [lambda layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) and hence was able to access the file at `/opt/mongo_certs/ca.pem`. (mongo_certs was the name of the zip file I uploaded).

The code of lambda is as follows

```py
import datetime
import os

from pymongo import MongoClient

# get the creds from env variables
MONGO_USER = os.environ['MONGO_USER']
MONGO_USER_PASSWORD = os.environ['MONGO_PASSWORD']
MONGO_CERT_PATH = os.environ['MONGO_CERT_PATH']
MONGO_HOSTS = os.environ['MONGO_HOSTS']
MONGO_REPLICA_SET_NAME = os.environ['MONGO_REPLICA_SET_NAME']
MONGO_URI = f'mongodb://{MONGO_USER}:{MONGO_USER_PASSWORD}@{MONGO_HOSTS}/?ssl=true&ssl_ca_certs={MONGO_CERT_PATH}&replicaSet={MONGO_REPLICA_SET_NAME}'

# create a mongoDB connection
MONGO_CLIENT = MongoClient(MONGO_URI)
TEST_COLLECTION_CONN = MONGO_CLIENT['someDB']['someCollection']


def write_to_mongoDB(event, context):
    try:
        data = {
            'createdDate': datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
            'message': 'written from aws lambda'
        }
        response = TEST_COLLECTION_CONN.insert_one(data)
        print('response =====>', response)
        return True
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
    return False
```

I get the following error when I test run the function:

```
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1108)
```

So I have a couple of questions:

1. Is this a recommended way to access MongoDB via self signed
   certificates (secuity wise)
2. Why is the above error happening as I can access the cluster from my
   EC2.

> Note: My lambda functions is running in the same VPC and security group as my EC2.

Thanks.

Comment: do you think the layer causing trouble, did you try deploying the certificate part of lambda

Comment: Yes the layer is attached to lambda function. I even checked if the file was accessible using `os.path.exists()`

Comment: how about file system permissions

Comment: As per their docs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html), i have read access to the directory.